# Maya Render Settings Problems

Tags: python, maya, renderer

I had 2 questions in which I am not sure if this can by done in-scene using python.

My Maya version is not installed with any Mental Ray. There are times in which when I opened files (that was installed with Mental Ray), I keep getting errors such as:

```
// Warning: file: /apps/Linux64/aw/maya2014/scripts/others/supportRenderers.mel line 77: The renderer "mentalRay" used by this scene, is not currently available. The Maya Software renderer will be used instead. //
// Error: file: /apps/Linux64/aw/maya2014/scripts/others/supportRenderers.mel line 82: setAttr: The attribute 'defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer' is locked or connected and cannot be modified. //
// Error: file: /apps/Linux64/aw/maya2014/scripts/others/unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow.mel line 415: The renderer mentalRay is not registered yet. //
// Error: line 1: The renderer mentalRay is not registered yet. //
```

I tried using the following code to 'rectify' the issue:

```
list = cmds.listAttr("defaultRenderGlobals", l=True)

for item in list:
    cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals." + item, l=False)

mel.eval('updateCurrentRendererSel("unifiedRenderGlobalsRendererSelOptionMenu");')
mel.eval('loadPreferredRenderGlobalsPreset("mayaHardware");')
```

but then I will get another bunch of error if I tried to open up my Render Settings

```
//Error: Object ‘tabForm’ not found.
```

And so, are there any ways in which this can be remedied in-scene

Attached is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Let me know if my answer below works out for you. If it doesn't share the exact errors you get, and possibly a screenshot of your render settings window.

Comment: @kartikg3 By the way, when I tried out your solution, I am not longer seeing `// Error: line 1: The renderer mentalRay is not registered yet. //` but whenever I open the render settings, I am getting the same as the screenshot I have pasted no matter which renderer I choose.. Having said that, I am seeing no errors or whatsoever in the editor

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* See the "Update" section below in this answer to find the full solution.

Why don't you just try unlocking and setting the `currentRenderer` value using `setAttr` itself.

```
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", l=False)    
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", "mayaHardware", type="string")
```

You are getting the error `//Error: Object ‘tabForm’ not found.` because the render settings window failed to load, probably because of unregistered mentalRay. So AVOID calling the following until current renderer is changed:

```
mel.eval('updateCurrentRendererSel("unifiedRenderGlobalsRendererSelOptionMenu");')
mel.eval('loadPreferredRenderGlobalsPreset("mayaHardware");')
```

***Update:***

From the updates in the question and the comments below, we come to understand that the problem here is that Maya fails to construct the render settings window's UI properly when it encounters a missing renderer or render settings errors. This leads to parent UI components, like the tabs and frames to not being built. As a result, when the renderer is switched, the render settings UI tries to load the corresponding settings into these tabs but cannot find them and stops.

To work around this, we can just set the render settings we want, delete the render settings window's UI completely and reload it. I wrote a quick function for this. This will fix it.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel


def remake_render_settings_ui(renderer="mayaSoftware"):
    """ Remakes the render settings window """
    # Unlock the render globals' current renderer attribute
    cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", l=False)    

    # Sets the current renderer to given renderer
    cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", renderer, type="string")

    # Deletes the render settings window UI completely
    if cmds.window("unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow", exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI("unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow")

    # Remake the render settings UI
    mel.eval('unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow;')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    remake_render_settings_ui(renderer="mayaHardware")
```

*Caveat:* This will not prevent the UI from getting lost again if the faulty renderer is somehow selected again. To prevent that, it is better to [unload](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/unloadPlugin.html) the renderer's plugin. In any case, if the above method is called again, the window should be fixed.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. While I tried your command, I am getting this issues, please see my screenshot whenever I tried to open up the Render Settings. And hence that is why I have implemented the mel commands. Even so, upon using that mel commands of mine, there are times in which as I switch between the renders, its tabs/contents are not updated according and it also shows `//Error: Object ‘tabForm’ not found.` in the editor

Comment: Which version of Maya are you using, and which version of Maya was used to create these scene files you are trying to open?

Comment: I am using Maya version 2014. The scene files I am trying to open, are most probably created in Maya 2012 (loaded with mentalray) and hence this is why I am seeing this message `// Warning: file: /apps/Linux64/aw/maya2014/scripts/others/supportRenderers.mel line 77: The renderer "mentalRay" used by this scene, is not currently available. The Maya Software renderer will be used instead. //`

Comment: Try: running my above script, then saving the file as a copy, restart maya. And then open the copy.

Comment: I will try it later on, but can I ask if it is possible not to have the saving of file and restarting of Maya? Not possible to "fix" everything within scene?

Comment: The problem here is Maya flips out when it tries to build the UI. So far I have not managed to fix that issue. I ll try a couple of things and see.

Comment: Hey @yan, can you try: `source unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow;` and then `unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow;`

And let me know?

Comment: Hey @kartikg3, I tried it after the `cmds.setAttr` command, as the Render Settings window got pop up, while I am seeing the tabs etc in the `MayaHardware` but as I am changing the renderer to either `MayaSoftware` or `MayaHareware2`, the tabs are not changing. It is still stuck onto the tabs of `MayaHardware`

Comment: Can you change it to software and try the above scripts again and see if it populates properly?

Comment: Okay, but it is still the same. Both hardware and hardware2 tabs are showing the tabs of the software. By the way, something I noticed in my previous method, there is this error in the log - `// Error: file: /apps/Linux64/aw/maya2014/scripts/others/unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow.mel line 1223: Object 'mayaSoftwareTabLayout' not found. // `

Comment: Ok @yan. I think it got it working. Check out the updated answer and let me know.

Comment: Hey @kartikg3, I tried yours and still it is not working. I have sort of found a 'hacked' workaround and I have just posted my answer as well. It seems that the crucial fact is that the scene file needs to be closed for it to be effected. Nevertheless please do me pointers if you have, pertaining to my answer

Comment: The render settings window gets popup with the renderer and the tabs set to Maya Hardware. However while changing the renderer to MayaSoftware for example, the tabs did not change. No errors will be shown unless I purposely click onto the MayaHardware tab (with the renderer at software). Error is as follows : `// Error: file: /apps/Linux64/aw/maya2014/scripts/others/unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow.mel line 1223: Object 'mayaSoftwareTabLayout' not found. // `

Comment: Thanks for your help as well. Have been seeing that the problem I encountered is due to a bug or something in Maya versions (installed with MR) and I would says your solution would helps them :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems that arises in the Render Settings while opening a scene file that contains traces of Mental Ray in a machine installed with ***no Mental Ray plugin***

For some reasons, despite unlocking and setting a renderer in the `defaultRenderGlobals` in the scene, the render settings will continue to have problems as mentioned in the thread post or comments in `kartikg3` answer.

I found a workaround which is -

- Unlock the `defaultRenderGlobals`
- Save the said file Delete any existing `unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow
  UI` + a few more mel commands
- Reload/Re-opening the scene

Seems to me that doing the first 2 steps within the scene, it does not rectify the issues in the Render Settings window unless I either close the current scene file by opening a new file session or reopen the file itself...

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

def unlockRenderer(renderer="mayaHardware2"):
    print "Unlocking and resetting current renderer"

    # Unlock the render globals' current renderer attribute
    cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", l=False)    

    # Sets the current renderer to given renderer
    cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.currentRenderer", renderer, type="string")

def saveFile():
    # Prompts User to resave the file, removing traces of Mental Ray
    mel.eval('SaveSceneAs;')

def reloadScene():
    recentFiles = []
    try:
        recentFiles = cmds.optionVar( query = 'RecentFilesList' )

    except:
        cmds.error("No recent files found!")

    curFile = cmds.file(query =True, loc = True)

    if curFile == "unknown":
        cmds.confirmDialog(title = 'Reload Scene', message = ('Reload Last Opened Scene?\n\n' + recentFiles[len(recentFiles)-1]), button = ['Cancel','OK'], defaultButton = 'OK', cancelButton = 'Cancel', dismissString = 'Cancel' )
        cmds.file( str(recentFiles[len(recentFiles)-1]), force = True, open = True)
        print "Opening Last Recent File - ", recentFiles[len(recentFiles)-1]
    else:
        cmds.confirmDialog(title = 'Reload Scene', message = ('Reload Current Scene?\n'), button = ['Cancel','OK'], defaultButton = 'OK', cancelButton = 'Cancel', dismissString = 'Cancel' )
        curFileLoc = cmds.file(query = True, location = True)
        cmds.file( curFileLoc , force = True, open = True)
        print "Re-Opening current file - ", curFileLoc

def main():
    unlockRenderer(renderer="mayaHardware2")
    saveFile()
    if cmds.window("unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow", exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI("unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow")
    mel.eval('resetAE()')
    mel.eval('buildNewSceneUI;')
    reloadScene()

main()
```

Something to note - At times, some errors such as `#// Error: file: /apps/Linux64/aw/maya2014/scripts/others/unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow.mel line 1074: setParent: Object 'unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow' not found. //` is still encountered, even after the file is reopened. It may differs accordingly to scene file